# Graduate level CS classes online?

Tags: education

I've been trying to find lists of graduate level CS classes that have had their lectures videotaped. There's a similar question on MathOverflow, which has compiled a fairly extensive list of stuff:

[Free online video lectures of mathematics courses](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free).

What I'm mostly interested in is finding links to materials like the following (which you can only really stumble on by accident through YouTube's recommended videos):

[CMU Advanced Optimization and Randomized Methods](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoYvVAiH3M5uvzhcaYajEtg).

I know this question doesn't really satisfy the QA format of the site, but this is by far the most widely read website that I know of for the target audience. Since the question was OK on MO I assume it's also OK here...

Comment: Perhaps you find [this link](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/lectures/Math-Videos/comb-videos.htm) interesting, although it might have more of a combinatorial flavor.

Comment: Different sites within Stack Exchange have different standards for what is an acceptable question. Also, the standards of any given site may change over time and the MO question you link is more than four years old. List questions are generally frowned upon ("[real questions have *answers*, not *items*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)") and [don't have a lot of support here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/20/what-about-list-questions)

Comment: Asking for a list of all courses with video recorded lectures is far too broad -- there are far too many questions.  Also, we don't want to be just a link farm.  Consequently, I'm afraid this question is not suitable here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I think you should consider reopening this question link farms are actually quite useful right now.